# How do I install MELPA packages via El-Get?

Tags: emacs, melpa, el-get

The El-Get documentation says that [El-Get supports
`package.el`](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get#el-get-elpa-and-packageel)
and the MELPA documentation shows [how to use MELPA with
`package.el`](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started). How do I
install MELPA packages using El-Get?

## Failed Attempt

I'm using Emacs 23, so `package.el` is not part of Emacs.  I
installed `package.el` using El-Get, but I'm not sure how to make
El-Get aware of MELPA. I tried adding

```
;; Based on http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started .

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  ;; The 't' means to append, so that MELPA comes after the more
  ;; stable ELPA archive.
  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

;; Add ELPA if necessary. Looking at the El-Get package.rcp recipe in
;; ~/local/opt/el-get/recipes it seems this is probably unnecessary.
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)
```

to my `init-package.el` which is sourced by El-Get, but I still don't
see the MELPA packages in El-Get (e.g. with `M-x el-get-list-packages`).

## Update

I added

```
(require 'el-get-elpa)
;; Build the El-Get copy of the package.el packages if we have not
;; built it before.  Will have to look into updating later ...
(unless (file-directory-p el-get-recipe-path-elpa)
  (el-get-elpa-build-local-recipes))
```

to my `init-package.el` as suggested in the accepted answer and now everything works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
(require 'el-get-elpa)
```

and then call `M-x el-get-elpa-build-local-recipes`: it creates special directory `../recipes/elpa` with recipes from elpa and el-get sees new recipes now.

Comment: Does `M-x el-get-elpa-build-local-recipes` need to be run periodically, or does it automatically update after the first time?

Comment: @echristopherson: I assume you only need to run it again to get definitions for new packages, since AFAIK the recipes shouldn't change often.