# What package manager should I use for emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, package-managers

I have been a vim user for years now and recently started to try out **emacs**. There are a lot of components available for this editor, like mail clients, IRC clients, etc. All these components need a package manager to update them and to make handling of them easier in general.

On **vim** there is a plethora of plugin managers (like Vundle or pathogen) and different people use different things.

On the other side, **emacs** includes `package.el` with recent versions (which is great to begin with), but there is also `el-get` and the `package.el` package list is pretty short.

Should I stick to `package.el` (and maybe extend the package list with [marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/))? Or do I need `el-get` for sane package management?

Comment: Also have a look at MELPA: http://melpa.milkbox.net/

Comment: http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/ has fewer packages than its unstable older sibling, but it has sane version numbers and, well, stable packages. Personally I like el-get and use it for everything, but package.el is certainly the path of least resistance.

Comment: el-get can encompass both ELPA [(see the github page)](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) and MELPA [(see this SO thread)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165158/how-do-i-install-melpa-packages-via-el-get), so it's probably your most flexible option.

Comment: @phils: FWIW: So far, I have to disagree about melpa-stable.milkbox.net. *None* of my libraries are listed there, for some reason. And they are all on "ordinary" MELPA. Yet they all are uploaded from *securely locked* EmacsWiki locations. So far, it is unclear just what distinguishes the two sites, and what "curating" is involved. (I'm waiting to hear back from Donald Curtis about this.)

Comment: @phils: I heard back from Donald about this. From his point of view, the "stable" MELPA site is in maintenance mode only. And the only reason that code like mine is not there is that no one has implemented uploading from the wiki for the "stable" site. Also, there is no "curating" done by anyone - no filtering to determine whether a package is stable, risky etc. The existence of two sites was requested by some package *developers* who wanted to distinguish dev versions of their packages from older ("stable") versions.

Comment: For sure; I would expect melpa-stable (like melpa) to work automatically, periodically detecting the latest revisions available. The difference being that melpa-stable only considers revisions which have been tagged as a release by their author. As you point out, there are package sources for which that interaction has not been implemented. I certainly agree that people should be aware of "ordinary" melpa as a (larger) source of packages, though -- and a great many people are very happy using it for pretty much everything, so clearly YMMV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a recent Emacs version then go with `package.el`.  And **add MELPA** to the repository list.

Also, it is **not** the case that all "packages" (or libraries) *need a package manager to update them and to make handling of them easier in general.*  There is a world of useful Emacs Lisp code out there that is not "packaged" and uploaded to a `package.el` repository.

More importantly, regardless of whether you use `package.el` to retrieve and "install" packages, you should learn the basics of loading, byte-compiling, and using Emacs Lisp code.  Don't just use `package.el` blindly, without understanding something about Lisp code.

The basics of "installing" Lisp code manually include the following:

1. In general, you will want to byte-compile libraries that you use, for better performance. Keep in mind this caveat, if you do so:

   1a. Load any **source** files (`*.el`) that define Lisp **macros** that are needed by any of the other Lisp libraries you use.

   1b. Then byte-compile (the macro-defining libraries and) the libraries that use the macro-defining libraries.  ***This is important.***  It is likely that the latest versions of the macro-using libraries need the *latest versions of the macros*, and if you compile them without having first *loaded* the latest macro definitions then you are asking for trouble.
2. Put any libraries you use in a directory that is in your `load-path`.  Said differently: set variable `load-path` in your init file (`~/.emacs`) to a value that includes all directories containing Lisp code that you use.
3. Generally, you want to use `(require 'foo)` in your own code (e.g. in your init file), to load library `foo`.
4. However, #3 works only if library `foo` (file `foo.el`) actually provides feature `foo`: `(provide 'foo)`.  If it does not, you can use `(load-library "foo")` instead.

   (Note the difference here between using `'foo` and `"foo"`: the first refers to feature `foo`; the second refers to files `foo.el` and `foo.elc`.
5. Finally, before you try to **use** a library, do yourself a favor and take a look at the `Commentary` section of the file header.  Often it tells you important things about using the library.  And even when it does not say something terribly important it might say something useful (e.g. a tip or two).

I mention 1-5 because I see too many (no, not many, but too many) new users just "installing" stuff  using a package manager and never taking a look at what the code they are installing is all about: what it is for, how to use it, etc.  If there is something in the `Commentary` then read it; the library author put it there to **help you**.

Beyond that, have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: Wilhelm: this was a really nice answer.  If it provided the information you needed, please consider accepting it so future users will recognize it easier.